# Creating 8 byte IV in Java

Tags: java, des, cbc-mode

Im new to cryptography in Java and I am trying to write a program to encrypt and decrypt a phrase using DES symmetric cipher, based on CBC mode of operation.

Can anyone tell me how to go about **creating an 8-byte initialization vector** and **how to cast the new IV into AlgorithmParameterSpec class?**

Also, **which packages should I import?**

Edit: Right now I have these lines:

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(); //create new secure random
byte [] iv = new byte[8]; //create an array of 8 bytes 
sr.nextBytes(iv); //create random bytes to be used for the IV (?) Not too sure.
IvParameterSpec IV = new IvParameterSpec(iv); //creating the IV
```

Is my above approach correct?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Comment: [java.security.SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html).

Comment: Can anyone tell me what the AlgorithmParameterSpec class is? And how is it used?

Comment: @user3180947 did you chek the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/AlgorithmParameterSpec.html) for it. See the section all *All Known Implementing Classes*

Comment: @A4L Yup I checked it out but I didnt really get it. Is there any place where I can see an example of the AlgorithmParameterSpec class being used in a real program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Till Now You are right.
the `Class IvParameterSpec` is used to pass Initial Vector to `Class Cipher`
After this create a `Cipher` as below

```
Cipher cipherInstance = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/NoPadding");
```

here `DES/CBC/NoPadding` is used because you are useing **DES** encryption in **CBC** mode.

Next is initializing it.

```
cipherInstance.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, Key, ivParameterSpec);
```

Parameters are:
**1st is mode of encryption either `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` or `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`

2nd is Secret Key You have generated using `Class SecretKey`

3rd is generated ivParameterSpec**

and last line is

```
outData = cipherInstance.doFinal(input);
```

if mode is **Decrypt** it will return decrypted data and if mode is **Encrypt** it will return encrypted data.

Last but important catch all the **Exceptions** properly.
And you are done

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible for you to tell me what is meant by "Cast the new IV into AlgorithmParameterSpec class"? Thanks again!

Comment: <b>AlgorithmParameterSpec<b/> is an Interface implemented by <b>IvParameterSpec<b/> and other like classes which are created to provide parameters to different Encryption algorithms like <b>DH, PBE, ECC, RC2, RC5, RSA, DSA</b>